# How to implement strategies selected at run time in Rust?

Tags: rust

I would like to write a simulation algorithm in Rust that has three main parts. The first part is a `struct` that maintains the current state of the system and associated methods to make allowed state transitions. The second part is a simulation strategy, this tells which state transition(s) to make next (e.g. I will have a slow but accurate simulation strategy and a quick but approximate strategy). Finally, I have a way to serialise the system after a simulation step was taken (e.g. one method writes the system to `csv` while another one to `json`).

I would like to choose both the simulation strategy and the serialisation method at run time.

Coming from Python, my first try for the main simulation loop looked like this:

```rust
let mut system = System { ... };
let simulator = GillespieAlgorithm { system: &mut system, ... };  // this will be dynamic eventually
let output_formatter = CSVFormatter { system: &system, ... };  // this will be dynamic eventually

output_formatter.start();

for _ in 1..100 {
  simulator.step();
  output_formatter.write_current_state();
}

output_formatter.stop();
```

Of course, this doesn't work because I want to borrow `system` twice with one of them being a mutable reference.

What would be the idiomatic Rust solution to this problem? My understanding is that I should somehow attach a behaviour dynamically to `System` instead of passing `system` to other `struct`s.

Comment: One simple solution is to pass `&mut system` to `step()` and `&system` to `write_current_state()`. The formatter object should maintain the state of the formatter between calls to `write_current_state()`, but it shouldn't need access to the system itself.

Comment: Also note that choosing the behavior at run-time is a separate issue from that of borrow checking. To do that, you would create a `Simulator` trait (with the `step` method) and an `OutputFormatter` trait (with the `write_current_output` method) and use trait objects to access them. This is described in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html).

Comment: Yes, my current solution is to pass the `system` to both `step` and `write_current_state`, but I was hoping in something better. My main problem with it is that `step` may have multiple smaller functions (for readability) and passing around `system` is not great. Also I would like to ensure that `output_formatter.start` is called with the same `system` as `output_formatter.write_current_state`.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342, I thought that I will need to use traits, but I'm not sure where exactly. If I just replace the current `GillespieAlgorithm` and `CSVFormatter` with a trait, I will still hit the same borrow checking error. So I was thinking that maybe I need to implement traits on `System` itself and dynamically import the right implementation... But I'm not sure I understood your comment well, I'm very new to Rust.

Comment: As I said at the beginning of my second comment, choosing the behavior at run-time is a separate issue from the borrow-checking error. You first need to tackle the borrow check issue, and only then proceed to turn your behavior into traits.

Comment: Passing the system down to helper functions can be avoided with a helper struct that contains `&System`. You'd create and destruct the helper inside `write_current_state()`, so there will be no borrow-check issues. This won't ensure that `start()` is called with the same system as `write_current_state()`; for that I'd add an `id() -> usize` method to system, and asserted that I always get the same ID. Finally, if you really want to reference the system, you can use `Rc<RefCell<System>>`; see [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You've mentioned in the comments, that you want to keep the `&mut system` in your simulation. Thats fine and you can still use system, as long as you're getting it via the `GillespieAlgorithm`. If you're fine to pass it to the formatter by method argument rather than constructor, this might be a solution for you ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7d57f2a36995594386f15e71e639fee4))

```
struct System();
struct GillespieAlgorithm<'a> { system: &'a mut System }
struct CSVFormatter();

fn main() {
    let mut system = System();
    let mut simulator : Box<dyn Algorithm> = Box::new(GillespieAlgorithm { system: &mut system });  // this will be dynamic eventually
    let output_formatter: Box<dyn Formatter> = Box::new(CSVFormatter());  
    output_formatter.start();

    for _ in 1..100 {
      simulator.step();
      output_formatter.write_current_state(simulator.borrow_system());
    }
    
    output_formatter.stop();
}

trait Algorithm {
    fn step(&mut self) {}
    fn borrow_system(&self) -> &System;
}

impl<'a> Algorithm for GillespieAlgorithm<'a> {
    fn step(&mut self) {}
    fn borrow_system(&self) -> &System {
        self.system
    }
}

trait Formatter {
    fn start(&self);
    fn write_current_state(&self, system: &System);
    fn stop(&self);
}

impl Formatter for CSVFormatter {
    fn start(&self) {}
    fn write_current_state(&self, _system: &System) {}
    fn stop(&self) {}
}
```

If you don't need the entire System in the CSVFormatter, you could also return a dedicated state struct in `step()` and pass this to your formatter.

Comment: According to [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69053621/how-to-implement-strategies-selected-at-run-time-in-rust#comment122043864_69053621), the OP needs `&System` available to `*Formatter::start()`, and would further like to ensure that that's the same system that is passed to `*Formatter::write_current_state()`.

Comment: Idiomatic Rust is a lot about getting rid of shared mutable objects. You could achieve such a behavior with refcell, but I wouldn't call it idiomatic rust anymore. Another solution could be to have a `Simulation::run_steps(n: usize) -> SimulationSummary` where SimulationSummary looks like `SimulationSummary { initial_state: SystemSummary, steps: Vec<StepSummary> }`

Comment: I largely agree with your reasoning, just pointing out what the OP lays out as requirements (or close to them). `RefCell` is widely used in Rust codebases, so I wouldn't call its use non-idiomatic, but it is somewhat of a "code smell".